# ROR проблема рендеринга данных из БД в index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть модель в которой два класса `Project - title todos` 
и`Todo - text complete`. У каждой своя миграция. Данные хранятся в БД и все работает. Но при рендеринге возникает проблема. Не могу получить `project.todos`. Я частично догадываюсь почему. Потому что, само todo задание хранится в `Todo text` и я присваиваю это в `Project todos` с помощью `seeds.rb`. В консоли если проверить `Project.all` `Todo.all` все работает как мне надо. Но проблема с рендерингом есть. Помогите, спасите!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя модель

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, required: false
end
```

Контроллер

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

Индекс

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <h2><%= project.title %></h2>

   <ul>
     <li><%= project.todos.inspect %></li>
   </ul>
<% end %>
```

Я специально поставил `.inspect` чтобы вам была видна картина. Если убрать то там будет просто идентификатор объекта. А мне бы получить именно все эти тексты Купить молоко и тд и тп. А что-то как-то не выходит. Кто знает пожалуйста подтолкните, буду благодарен!

Comment: Не вижу, в чём проблема. Данные инспектом выводятся, с виду даже правильные. Что значит "не могу получить"?

Comment: А. Кажется, понял. Но всё-таки, приведите то, как попытались вывести отдельные `Todo`. Включая скриншот результата (в котором только идентификаторы, как я понимаю).

Comment: @D-side не даже, а действительно правильные. Но нужно без скобочек это все получить, все эти строки хранятся в атрибуте todos объекта Project и если убрать инспект будет id объекта и все. А нужен сам текст.

Comment: @D-side вот Project - [#<Project id: 1, title: "Семья", todos: "Заменить масло в двигателе до 23 апреля", created_at: "2018-07-05 14:19:03", updated_at: "2018-07-05 14:19:04">                           а вот Todo - <Todo id: 2, text: "Заменить масло в двигателе до 23 апреля", isCompleted: false, project_id: 1, created_at: "2018-07-05 14:19:04", updated_at: "2018-07-05 14:19:04"> Каждый text(Todo) присваивается Project  с помощью project_id. И работает все как надо. Но почему в рендеренге я получаю муть

Comment: @D-side если убрать инспект то вместо тодо задания там будет #<Todo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000055d4e8b90fd8>

Comment: Да не в комментарии, в вопрос. Пример вьюхи, который вы пытались вывести отдельные Todo'шки.

Comment: @karaname, зачем вам поле todos в проекте? Ваши тудушки - это отдельная модель, они не должны храниться внутри проекта. По запросу `project.todos` база делает выборку и выдаёт вам список тудушек для конкретного проекта (это называется ActiveRecordRelation), вам этот список нужно точно так же итерировать через each, чтобы отобразились данные

Comment: @Василиса + , пофиксил, работает

Comment: @karaname, это прекрасно :) Я вам про это в комментах ещё к предыдущему вопросу писала :) И там же есть мой вопрос, на который вы так и не ответили

Comment: @Василиса аха) извините, работаю